# curl: provide user and password for apache .htaccess file

Tags: .htaccess, curl, apache2

I am using [`cURL`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CURL) to test some RESTful APIs. Some of these APIs are served from an Apache machine, and protected with user/password combination using simple `.httaccess` files.

Is there a way to provide cURL with a username / password combination as arguments?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Use this curl option for the commandline

```
-u "User:Password"
```

More details about this parameter can be found from [here](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#--user).

Answer (score 4):

You can use this curl command for example:

```
curl -A "Mozilla" -L 'http://user:password@localhost/api/someapi.php'
```